# AAPT: error: '+@id/nav_nightlife' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am developing a tourism app and this is my code, but got the above error. please help. Not able to sync code to my virtual device.

the following is the error:
AAPT: error: '+@id/nav_nightlife' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

xml layout code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_restaurant_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_hotel_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_camera_enhance_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sport"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_sports_handball_black_36"
            android:title="@string/menu_sports"/>
        <item
            android:id="+@id/nav_nightlife"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_wine_bar_black_24"

            android:title="@string/menu_nightlife"/>
        <item
            android:id="+@id/menu_shopping"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_shopping_bag_black_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_shopping"/>
        <item
            android:id="+@id/menu_public_services"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_public_black_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_public_services"/>







    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: the `+` must come after the `@` but you have it before.

Change `+@id/nav_nightlife` to `@+id/nav_nightlife`. Note that you will have to make a similar change to many of your other ids as well.